# RxJava2 ObservableEmitter is not getting created

Tags: rx-java2

I have a data provider, where I can run a query that looks like this, to get prices. Please assume `getPrices` is defined.

```
void batchGet(String[] s,ObservableEmitter<Map<String,Double> y){
  List<List<String>> prts = Lists.partition(Lists.newArrayList(s), BATCH_SIZE);
        for(List<String>batchList : prts ) {
            String[] batch = new String[batchList.size()];
            batchList.toArray(batch);
            try {
                Map<String, Double> res = getPrices(batch);
                y.onNext(res );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                y.onError(e);
            }
        }
        y.onComplete();
}
```

I am calling the method above using the following code:

```
Observable<Quote> ret = Observable.create(y -> {
            batchGet(symbols, y)});
ret.subscribe(q -> saveQuotes(q));
```

later, I noticed that there was a `NullPointerException` when `y.onNext(...)`
 is called, due to `y==null`. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I doubt `y` is null there but you can add null checks before batchGet or even before y.onNext to see if y is really null. In such odd cases, the bug is usually in the code not shown so I'd double check getPrices for possible null or that it returns null that is rejected by (a non null) y.onNext call.

Comment: removing the additional {} seems to have fixed this... so weird